# expected value and variance of function

Tags: statistics

I am confused about calculating the expected value of a function that is split, the question looks as follows:

[image: question]

and my solution is:

[image: sol]

Which are incorrect.. can someone please help me to correct the answers. Or tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you write $\int xf(x)dx$ but then you calculate $\int xF(x)dx$. Calculate first $f(x)$ from $F(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct equation for calculating the expectation of *a continuous random variable* from its *probability density function*.   However, that was *not* what you had been given.

You were given a Cumulative Distribution Function that belongs to a *discrete random variable*; and thus has a probability *mass* function.

> $$p_X(x) =\begin{cases} 5/10 &:& x=0\\ 1/10 &:& x=1\\ 2/10 &:& x=2\\ 1/10 &:& x=3 \\ 1/10 & :& x=3.5 \\ 0 &:&\textsf{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

As such the expectation is not an integral, but a series: $$\mathsf E(X) ~=~ \sum_{x\in\{0,1,2,3,3.5\}} x~p_X(x)$$

And similarly for the variance.